# Remove same index elements in two lists based on first list tuple value

Tags: python, python-3.x

if i have two Python lists as following:

```
indices_tuple_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(3,1)]
values_list = ['a','b','c']
```

I would like to remove in both lists the same indexes based on a given value.
This value represents the second element in the `indices_tuple_list` tuples.
So, if it matches, the tuple, and the corresponding element in `values_list` must be removed.

#### Examples:

Given the value 1:

Result lists:

```
indices_tuple_list = [(1,2)]
values_list = ['b']
```

Given the value 2:

Result lists:

```
indices_tuple_list = [(1,1),(3,1)]
values_list = ['a','c']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip` and a list comprehension.

```
remove_val = 2
result = [i for i in zip(indices_tuple_list, values_list) if i[0][1] != remove_val]
result
[((1, 1), 'a'), ((3, 1), 'c')]

new_indices, new_values = map(list, zip(*result))
```

**Output**

```
new_indices
[(1, 1), (3, 1)]
new_values
['a', 'c']
```

Comment: `zip` is its own inverse, so you could do `new_indices, new_values = zip(*result)` or `new_indices, new_values = map(list, zip(*result))` if you wanted the results to be lists as in the OP.

Comment: @pault even better! Updated now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
to_remove = 1

indices_tuple_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(3,1)]
values_list = ['a','b','c']

new_indices_tuple_list = [v for v in indices_tuple_list if v[1] != to_remove]
new_value_list = [v for i, v in enumerate(values_list) if indices_tuple_list[i][1] != to_remove]

print(new_indices_tuple_list)
print(new_value_list)
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 2)]
['b']
```

For `to_remove = 2` the output is:

```
[(1, 1), (3, 1)]
['a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(value):
    for index, tuple in enumerate(indices_tuple_list):
        if tuple[1] == value:
            indices_tuple_list.pop(index)
            values_list.pop(index)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip`:

```
indices_tuple_list = [(1,1),(1,2),(3,1)]
values_list = ['a','b','c']

remov = 1
new_indices, new_values = [], []

for x, y in zip(indices_tuple_list, values_list):
    if x[1] == remov:
        continue
    new_indices.append(x)
    new_values.append(y)

print(new_indices)
print(new_values)

# [(1, 2)]
# ['b']
```